# an issue with apache2 restart

Tags: apache2

I am a newcomer to the Linux world. I installed apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin and created configured virtual hosts. Everything was working fine. After installing laravel, problems of being unable to restart or reload apache2 appeared.

When typing:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I receive:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When running the command:

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

I receive:

> Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.

And when I run the command:

```
journalctl -xe
```

I receive:

> [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR

Comment: Showing us a single line from `journalctl -xe` won't be much helpful, can you add more details please?. Also, are there any info in the error log file? Unless you changed it, the file should be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Hi Elder Geek, Thanks for response, i have attached all the output of the journalctl -xe below

Comment: I could not attach all the lines from the journalctl -xe.It is too long to send here. Also I tried to viw the error log file,but nothing is clear some stange and weird symbols.I couldn't get any data

Comment: this error: drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR
is repeated for all the lines

Comment: hi any update please?

Comment: What is the output for apachectl -t ?